# access web app - filter query criteria issue

Tags: function, ms-access, sharepoint

I have an access web app published on SharePoint. I have created a table which contain a column "Start Date" formatted as Date/Time. I'm trying to build a query which will return me all records from the current week. Here is the expression:

```
DatePart("ww", [Start Date]) = DatePart("ww", ToDay()) and Year( [Start Date]) = Year(ToDay())
```

It return me the following error:
[image]

For some reason the `Date()` function is no more available in expressions.
So I replaced `Date()` by `ToDay()`

```
DatePart("ww", [Start Date]) = DatePart("ww", Date()) and Year( [Start Date]) = Year(Date())
```

Bu without success, I get following error:
[image]

My OS is win 10 and I'm using Access 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just had this same issue and got through it! Here's how I converted the desktop version of the expression into something the Web App version can parse:

[image: queryexample]

Just realized now that I had the "Show" boxes checked for the expressions, so make sure to uncheck if you're not trying to output the values matched in the query :P

In the event the imgur image goes down, you need to set your first Field to something in the form `DatePart(Week,[Work.StartDate])` with the criteria `DatePart(Week,Today())`, then a second Expression with Field `Year([Work.StartDate])` and Criteria `Year(Today())`. Expressions 3 and 4 are there to do this same check on the FinishDate, but the Criteria is in the 'or:' line rather than being evaluated to AND.